# C++ - Effective and efficient way of linking functions to triggers

Tags: c++, function, user-interface, function-pointers

The UI system in my program currently works by assigning function pointers of the type `void(*)()` to *trigger elements* (quads on the screen, keys on the keyboard) with a specifiable *call condition* which will be compared to the actual condition of the key (using GLFW), mouse button or cursor every frame to determine whether the callback function should be called.
A condition for a key could be `KeyCondition(PRESS, LEFT_SHIFT)` which would call the callback bound to the key if the key was pressed while left shift is being held down.

My problem is that I can only assign these buttons functions of the type `void(*)()`, which disables me to pass arguments to a button callback.
If for example I wanted to make a button light up when the cursor hovers over it, I would have to create a designated function `void highlightButtonA()` which sets the color of button `A` to a higher value internally, while I would of course much rather be able to set the callback to something like `void offsetColor(unsigned int buttonIndex, float r, float g, float b, float a)` and pass individual parameters to each callback.

Is there any way to do this? Is there some function pointer which can point to a function of any shape and will store parameters somehow? How much should I worry about the performance of these solutions? My program has to be able to handle multiple key/button presses per second and still be stable, as it is a fast-paced shooter game.

Comment: Have you looked into using Qt? They have a system of [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) that is very well suited for binding functions to triggers.

Comment: This sounds like you are looking for c++11 and c++14 lambdas with closures that contain your variables.

Comment: @CoryKramer Isn´t a Qt slot the same as a function pointer? It says they are member functions but in order to store the connections between signals and slots I imagine you´d have to store a pointer to the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use non-capturing lambdas that decay to function pointers, something like this:

```
button.OnMouseHover([]{ offsetColour(buttonIndex, r, g, b, a); });
```

just remember that `buttonIndex` and other args to `offsetColour` should be literals as the lambda cannot capture variables from the enclosing scope.

Comment: is there a reason why the lambda cannot capture any variables?

Comment: because capturing lambda cannot decay to function pointer, as it's a statefull object now (to store captured vars)